# Getting full logs from GAE

Tags: google-app-engine, logging

I'm not able to get logs of my GAE application, no matter if I try using GAE admin panel, nor `appcfg.py --severity=0 --end_date=2010-03-07 request_logs . logs`.

It looks like I'm only able to browse latest logs in admin, or filter/download ERROR logs. DEBUG/INFO/WARNING ones from past days are innaccessible (i.e. GAE admin doesn't show any entries and appcfg.py returns: `Copied 0 records.`..

And no, it's not that there was no logging then :) What could be the reason?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

App Engine only stores logs for a limited time, with each severity going into the buckets it applies to (eg, ERROR goes into ERROR, WARN, DEBUG, .. buckets, while WARN goes into WARN, DEBUG, ... buckets). Data from buckets gets evicted by newer data, or after some time interval - it's likely your older entries have been evicted for one of those reasons.